# How to create a simple strucutre for a React-Redux-ElectronJS application

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, electron

After reviewing and unsuccessfully trying to understand the code structure behind Hardchor's [Timesheet's](https://github.com/hardchor/timesheets), I was hoping if any one could propose and explain a strucutre for a React-Redux-ElectronJS application

The structure could be made to accomodate processing in the main and renderer process as well as a global store to interact with both processes.

A beginner's explanation will be very helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can use [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate)

Comment: That helps to build for just React with Electron. I want to integrate Redux as well

Comment: Redux is included in boilerplate

Comment: Okay, spoke too soon. Thank you. Don't you agree that it is quite complex?

Comment: Can someone please explain the structure. It seems too complex

Answer (score 0):

A basic and clean structure will be [like](https://gist.github.com/yashodhandivakaran/56618d7f83c35b9f723e140c5619030e)

```
<your_project>
  |- app
     |- src
        |- main.js
        |- components
           |- component1
           |  |- index.js
           |  |- actions
           |  |  |- index.js
           |  |- reducer
           |  |  |- index.js
           |  |- sagas
           |     |- sagas1.js
           |     |- sagas2.js
           |- component2
           |  |- index.js
           |  |- actions
           |  |  |- index.js
           |  |- reducer
           |  |  |- index.js
           |  |- sagas
           |     |- sagas1.js
           |     |- sagas2.js
           |- reducer
           |  |- index.js
           |- action
           |  |- index.js
           |- sagas
              |- index.js
```

Every component will be having its own action, reducer, sagas this will be help full as when you require any change in a component the just navigate in that component dir structure.

Top level reducer index.js will import reducers of all other components, similarly top level action and sagas index.js import action and sagas from components respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this repo [Desktop](https://github.com/yashodhandivakaran/Desktop). This has integration with React, Redux, React Router, Redux-Saga with Webpack as a bundler. Also, the app structure is not that complex.